# How to display lightbox background while ajax loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to display ajax loader/spinner image with transparent lightbox typed background in the whole screen. Any idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these out:

http://codepen.io/collection/HtAne

Take one of the `.loaders` - put it in a `#loaderContainer` and then:

```
#loaderContainer{
     position:absolute; // or fixed
     background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); //to your preference
     width:100%; height:100%;
     top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; // not always necessary
     text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; 
//you'll have to tweak it to get it centered, but it shouldn't be too hard

}
```

Comment: In case it matters, rgba does not support IE8 and below. That's why I tend to lean towards using opacity. However, if just supporting modern browsers rgba has the added benefit of not applying the transparency to child elements (which is why with opacity you need to have the lightbox as a sibling of the loading icon instead of a parent)

Answer (score 1):

A strategy I often use.

1. Make a containing div
2. Create a child div that will be fixed behind that is transparent
3. Create a sibling div that will have the loading animation as the background

The reasoning is that you can have the transparent lightbox with its own transparency and the loading gif will be at full opacity

### css

```
.modal-overlay {
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.6;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#ajaxLoadingBox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: #333 url('../img/loader.gif') no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

### html

```
<!-- ajax loading dialog -->
<div>
  <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
  <div id="ajaxLoadingBox"></div>
</div>
```